# Can Mercer's theorem fail without positivity?

Tags: functional-analysis, trace, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $X = [0,1]$ and $K: X \times X \to \mathbb C$ continuous and self-adjoint, meaning that $K(y, x) = \overline {K(x,y)}
$. It defines a compact, even Hilbert-Schimdt, self-adjoint convolution operator $T_K$ on $L^2(X)$. Call the eigenvalues $(\lambda_n)_{n \geq 1}$ and orthonormal eigenfunctions $(f_n)_{n \geq 1}$.

Mercer's theorem ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem)) says that when $T_K$ is positive (meaning all $\lambda_n \geq 0$), the series
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \lambda_n f_n(x) \overline {f_n(y)}$$
converges uniformly on $X \times X$ (necessarily to $K(x, y)$, which is the $L^2$-limit).

---

If have not found any reference that discusses whether the condition that $T_K$ is positive, is necessary.

Can the theorem fail if $T_K$ is not positive?

For a counterexample I don't mind replacing $[0, 1]$ by some other compact Riemannian manifold $X$ with boundary.